Integration of function in Mathematica where the variable has dimension
I want to Integrate a function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-a}$ where both $x$ and $a$ have the dimension of length.
After doing the integration in Mathematica it is returning the solution $\log(x-a)$. But here the argument inside $\log$ which is $(x-a)$, is not dimensionless. One of the obvious way to make the argument of the log dimensionless, is to consider the solution of the form $\log\left(\dfrac{x-a}{a}\right)$. But how to generate this solution in Mathematica?
My Code
f[x_] := 1/(x - a);
Integrate[f[x], x]

Output
Log[-a + x]

I will be glad if someone can help me.

The definite integral Assuming[x > 2 a > 0, Integrate[1/(u - a), {u, 2 a, x}]] does what you want.

@StephenLuttrell How you found the limit?

If you provide a lower limit for your integral, which of course should be a length, I think your dimensions will cancel.

There is a Tech Note about Symbolic Calculations with Units. It has a (short) section about using quantities inside Integrate.
What seems to work is to use a definite integral with either Quantity or QuantityVariable.
Assuming[a > x, 
 Integrate[1/(Quantity[x, "Meters"] - Quantity[a, "Meters"]), 
  {Quantity[x, "Meters"], Quantity[0, "Meters"], Quantity[x, "Meters"]}]]

Assuming[a > x, 
 Integrate[1/(QuantityVariable[x, "Length"] - QuantityVariable[a, "Length"]),
  {QuantityVariable[x, "Length"], 0, QuantityVariable[x, "Length"]}]]


Note: Do not get confused by the ordinary-looking blue x and y in my second input cell – It is not x but QuantityVariable[x, "Length"] (which is visible on the tooltip).
